# Package tikz Error: Unknown chain ``chain''

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I'm trying to compile the first example from Section 46.2
"Starting and Continuing a Chain" of the pgfmanual v3.0.1a (p. 541):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
% The chain is called just "chain"
\node [on chain] {A};
\node [on chain] {B};
\node [on chain] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

my code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Same as above, using the scope shorthand
{ [start chain=1]
\node [on chain] {A};
\node [on chain] {B};
\node [on chain] {C};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is the error message:

```
! Package tikz Error: Unknown chain ``chain''.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \node [on chain]
                     {A};
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.9 \node [on chain]
                     {A};
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on debug.log.
```

Version of my packages via

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\listfiles
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

is

```
tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
 pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the relevant library `scopes` (for the shorthand).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Same as above, using the scope shorthand
{[start chain=1]
\node [on chain] {A};
\node [on chain] {B};
\node [on chain] {C};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```